# Is it possible to have a digital game that you bought (on eshop) on 2 or more SD cards?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I was wondering if there is any way of getting a game that you bought on eshop onto multiple sd cards. Since I bought my first game on eshop and now I'm thinking of getting a new SD card.

Is it possible to move my games there?

Answer (score 1):

For the 3DS, you can easily just connect the SD card to a computer to copy the games over, or plug in the new SD card into the 3DS and download it again.

None of this is considered software piracy, because the SD card data are all encrypted and will only work for your specific 3DS (even the saved games).  You're free to copy the data as you wish.